# Use theory of congruence to prove.....

Tags: integers

Use the theory of congruence to prove that $17|(2^{3n+1} +3\times5^{2n+1})$ for all integer $n\geq1$
$(2^{3n+1} +3\times5^{2n+1})$=$2\times8^n+15\times25^n$ 
=$17\times8^{n-1}+374\times25^{n-1}+25^{n-1}-8^{n-1}$

=$25^{n-1}-8^{n-1}$
=$8^{n-1}-8^{n-1}$ [since $25\equiv 8\mod 17)$
=$0\mod 17$

$0$ is divisible by $17$

Is this correct?

Comment: Powers of $3.5$ will not even be integers ...

Comment: Induction would be more straightforward...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen OP probably meant $3\cdot 5$, and an edit is waiting to be approved.

Comment: Hint: can you simplify $25$ modulo $17$?

Comment: Note that $25^{n-1} - 8^{n-1}$ is always a multiple of $25-8 = 17$ ($a-b$ always divides $a^n - b^n$).

Comment: You mean $25^(n-1)\equiv 8^(n-1)$(MOD 17)?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from here:
$$\begin{align}2\times8^n+15\times25^n&\equiv2\times8^n+15\times (17+8)^n\equiv\\
&\equiv2\times 8^n+15\times 8^n\equiv\\
&\equiv17\times 8^n\equiv 0 \pmod{17}.\end{align}$$